# Adding form fields when a new user registers with application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to add a field to the `users` table created by Laravel 5. I've modified the migration to add that field:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->string('my_new_field'); // Added this field
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    ...    
}
```

I'm using the default authentication system provided by Laravel. Whenever a new user registers, I need `my_new_field` to be set to some value. How (and where) do I do that?

The `AuthController` handles the authentication process. It uses the `trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` where the `postRegister()` function handles the registration requests. But where are the actual values inserted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `create()` method in `App\Services\Registrar` is responsible for creating a new `User` instance. I added the field to this function:

```
   /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    public function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'my_new_field' => 'Init Value'
        ]);
    }
```

According to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#authenticating-users),

> To modify the form fields that are required when a new user registers
>   with your application, you may modify the `App\Services\Registrar`
>   class. This class is responsible for validating and creating new users
>   of your application.
>
> The `validator` method of the Registrar contains the validation rules
>   for new users of the application, while the `create` method of the
>   Registrar is responsible for creating new User records in your
>   database. You are free to modify each of these methods as you wish.
>   The Registrar is called by the `AuthController` via the methods
>   contained in the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait.

**UPDATE Feb 03, 2016**
Laravel 5.2
The settings found in the app/Services/Registrar.php file have been moved to app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

I also had to make this field fillable in the `User` model:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
     ...
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'my_new_field'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update...this was driving me nuts !@!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a default value to the field like that:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->string('my_new_field')->default('init_value'); // Added this field
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    ...    
}
```

Alternativeley, just use a new migration to add the column in case the create migration has already been executed:

```
class AddMyNewFieldToUsersTable extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table) {
            $table->string('my_new_field')->default('init_value'); // Added 
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table) {
            $table->dropColumn('my_new_field');
        });
    }
}
```

If you do not wish to use db defaults, you could also set this value in the controller within the `store` method:

```
public class UsersController extends BaseController {

    // ...

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $user = new User;
        $user->fill($request->all());
        $user->my_new_field = 'init_value';
        $user->save();

        // return whatever
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Given the Information you gave in the comments here is a little guidance:

In the `AuthController` (/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php) add the following method (this overrides the default of the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers-trait which can be found [here](https://codeclimate.com/github/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php))

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $user = $this->create($request->all()); // here the values are inserted
    $user->my_new_field = 'init_value';     // here would be the place to add your custom default
    $user->save();                          // maybe try to do all that in a single transaction...

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Im not quite sure if this works out of the box, but it should get you startet.

Comment: Yes, that would work when setting a default value for all users. What if the value isn't the same for all users?

Comment: then you would need to provide more information on the conditions ;)

Comment: Which controller would that be?

Comment: The one where you store the users... probably `UsersController`?

Comment: Storing the users is handled by Laravel. And that is what I need to know - how do I modify that to add my field's value to the newly registered user.

Comment: Yes, that works. But I found a [cleaner solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28958066/1492578).

Answer (score 0):

Open the trait located at (for Laravel 5.2 AuthController)

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php
```

Here you can easily find interesting methods that will responsible for login and register user.

These are

```
getRegister() // responsible for showing registration form

postRegister() // responsible for processing registration request

getLogin() // responsible for showing login form

postLogin() // responsible for authentication user
```

These methods are called every time, when you will access specific route (auth/register or auth/login) i.e User registration & User login

Hope this will clear some concepts !!